# Download spreadsheet to android studio app with code

Tags: android

Hi I've done a lot of research already but I still can't find a good explanation for what callback does in android studio.

For example what function does call back do in the following methods:

```
     public DownloadWebpageTask(AsyncResult callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
}
```

Comment: how does your code have something to do with `android studio` ? Is there `DownloadWebpageTask` class built in `Android` ?

Comment: yes something similiar to that. Could you explain what callback does

Comment: I mean: I think `DownloadWebpageTask` here is your defined class, and then only know what it really does.  Is it built in ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your example code is from this article:

http://blogs.telerik.com/androidteam/posts/15-01-21/google-spreadsheet-as-data-source-android

The function you are referring to is a constructor to allow an object to be passed into the class that can be used to asynchronously notify when the class has finished its processing.

When the class has finished its background processing (it extends an AsyncTask) it calls `callback.onResult(table);` to signal that processing has completed and pass the JSON back to whoever created the class.

This design is used as the processing potentially can take a long time and the program does not want to block the main UI thread, so it uses AsyncTask to spawn a new worker thread and then uses the callback to know when the thread has finished.